# How do I use VBA to keep the value of a cell in Excel with a limit and loop when needed?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm working with some data that involves longitudinal degrees in column **A**.

- Column **B** holds the value of **A***n* - **A***(n-1)*.
- The values in column **A** are changing and making a loop, always between 0 and 360.

The problem is that when the value in **A***24* is, say, **358.2244** and the value in **A***25* is **2.4488** the value in **B***24* becomes negative.

The value being displayed is **-355.7756**, which is technically correct, but I want only positive values, so according to my requirement, **4.2244** should be displayed in that cell. What would the workaround for this using data validation or VBA be? I'm using Excel 2003 and Excel 2007.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead `=An - A(n-1)` use `=IF(An - A(n-1) < 0, 360 + (An - A(n-1)), An - A(n-1))`